# How can I get values from a custom post type depending on where I click on my SVG map?

Tags: php, custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

Here's what I would like to achieve (desktop only): https://www.icifaubourgboisbriand.com/en/stores/

When I click on my SVG map, I would like to display an information card for each store.

I have already created my custom post type "stores" and also the card HTML.

```
<div class="store-card">

    <div class="content">

        <div class="address">
            <span>Address</span><br>
            <span><?php the_field('store_address'); ?></span>
        </div>

        <div class="opening-hours">
            <span><?php the_field('store_opening_hours'); ?></span><br>
       
        </div>

     </div>
</div>
```

But now I don't know how to get my values for each store created in my CPT. How can I do that? For instance, when I click on a specific store, I want its name and its opening hours to be displayed. I haven't figured out how to make it happen.

Many thanks!

Comment: This is going to involve a bunch of code, some of it Javascript. It's not a simple answer to write up. The site you're trying to emulate seems to use WordPress, though; you might be able to get a head start by contacting them and asking them how they did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question will probably be marked off-topic because you're asking about a plugin, Advanced Custom Fields, but here's the answer anyway - you need to add the 'post id' to your call of `the_field()`, so that it's looking up the custom fields set in each of your custom post type's posts. See https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is what I was looking for. I'll try to figure out the other things with Javascript and stuff.